# Creating an integer from three bool values as bits in C++

Tags: c++, c, boolean

I have three `bool` values that represent bits. I want to have an integer in the form

```
true true true = 7
false true false = 2
```

I have

```
int val = 4*boolVal1 + 2*boolVal2 + boolVal3;
```

Is there another way, maybe even simpler?

Comment: Just fyi, shouldn't "true true true" result in a 7? Otherwise all formulas so far are wrong...

Comment: `int val = 4*boolVal1 + 2*boolVal2 + boolVal3;` will give 7 when you have true true true not 8

Comment: Correct, I just posted it wrong. Thx for correcting!

Answer (score 27):

You might find it clearer to use bitwise operators instead of multiplication and addition:

```
int val = (boolVal1 << 2) | (boolVal2 << 1) | boolVal3;
```

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use Horner's method:

`int val = (((boolVal1 << 1) | boolVal2) << 1) | boolVal3.`

This also makes it easier to add or remove variables from the middle of the statement without having to change all the other coefficients.

However, this might be a little less obvious to the reader.

Comment: Not that it's likely to matter, but I'm curious whether - with common compilers - it might perform worse due to having a sequential ordering in the evaluation: would be interesting to know if any/all of their optimisers can generate code that can be parallelised on a CPU instruction pipeline....

Comment: @Tony, You'd have to look at the machine code, but I would expect modern compilers to notice there is no branching inside the parentheses and unwind this pretty cleanly.

Answer (score 4):

Other than the multiplication and bitshifting, you could also use an enum to document the relationship.  Not normally worth the effort, but just for completeness...

```
enum Encoding
{ 
    Flag3 = 1,      NotFlag3 = 0,
    Flag2 = 1 << 1, NotFlag2 = 0,
    Flag1 = 1 << 2, NotFlag1 = 0
};

int val = (boolVal1 ? Flag1 : NotFlag1) |
          (boolVal2 ? Flag2 : NotFlag2) |
          (boolVal3 ? Flag3 : NotFlag3);
```

Why on earth would you bother with this?  It's just a bit more general, so you can potentially vary the Encoding values later without having to touch the potentially distributed code using actual values (for example, if you realised you'd left out a bit compared to the format of some file or network data you needed to parse, you can add it in just one place and recompile).  Of course it's better just to provide a single encode / decode function anyway, and if you're adding new flags you'll still need it.

While having Flag1 and NotFlag1 may seem pointless, it's often the case that you have something like mutually exclusive values like say Sticky and Floating, or Male and Female, and there's no particular reason to force clients to check for say Floating as !Sticky or Female as !Male etc..

Comment: The `NotFlag`s are not very helpful here. You would still check `(value & Flag2) == NotFlag2` if you wanted to find out if Flag2 is cleared. Besides, `?:` might create slower code than multiplication (branching vs. arithmetic operation). Also, I find it handy to overload operators `|`, `&`, `^` and `~` for such enums so that the type is preserved -- I even have a macro for it.

Comment: @user946850: often a function (especially C functions) ask callers to encode a parameter from flags, so the distributed calling code - of which there can be an arbitrary amount and the "cleanliness" thereof is therefore very important, can OR together Flags and "NotFlag"s quite happily without needing do test for flags - that's steps consolidated within the implementation of the called function(s), so much more easily maintained.  And yes, when enums are being used as proper values in the client code - and not just for encoding a paramter - proper operators are worth having.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the endianness you could also use implementation-defined behaviour and bitsets, little-endian version:

```
union foo {
        unsigned int the_int;
        struct {
                unsigned int bit3:1
                unsigned int bit2:1
                unsigned int bit1:1
        };
};
```

and then to set them:

```
foo.bit1 = true;
foo.bit2 = false;
foo.bit3 = true;
```

and to read:

```
foo.the_int;
```

The big-endian version has the bits reversed and a lot of padding (29 bits if `unsigned int` is 32bits wide) in front.